# Specify <DIV> when querying people "About Me"

Tags: content-query-web-part, query, fast-search, kql

I'm working on a "people directory" using a search query on the active directory. As it stands now I'm just using our group name, which is part of a large company. This get's all of the employee's in our group, however it picks up some extra people that use our group name in their "About Me" profile.

However, only people in our group have the group name in their "Sub Management Unit". I'm trying to find out how to query using the query web-part on just the sub management group so as to only pick up people in the group.

I went into the code on the page to see if i could find some managed property time that wasn't included in the query builder but I didn't find anything definitive for the Sub Management Unit, although I did try many.

Help me refine my question if it's unclear.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first find the crawled property from the People category matching the internal name of your UPA property. If it's not mapped to a managed property, then map it to one, and use that for your query :)

Comment: Not sure what most of that means, HOWEVER! I will research and come back. It'll probably be about 4 days before I can work on this issue again. Thank you very much for the direction. I'll let you know how it went. Thank you.

Comment: If you get stuck leave a comment.